# Best F/OSS IDE for Python Web Development (Windows or Linux)?

Tags: python, ide

Would like to know what is the best F/OSS IDE for Python Web development.  I've always used vim myself, but I'm increasingly interested in having a tool that integrates syntax checking/highlighting, source control, debugging, and other IDE goodies.

I use both Windows and Linux as desktops, so recommendations for either platform are welcome!

Thanks,
-aj

Comment: @Jeff, Windows or Linux (but not Mac).  I'll update the question.

Comment: AJ, there's a question for Python IDEs here on SO. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/81584/what-ide-to-use-for-python

Comment: @GmonC true, but I am coming at this from the perspective of a Web application developer.  I'm not so sure some of the tools listed in the other thread are suited for editing HTML, Javascript, CSS, etc.  Thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Might take some getting used to but [Eclipse](http://www.eclipse.org/) with the python extension - [PyDev](http://pydev.org/) - works for me. It took a bit of getting-used-to though as Eclipse is generally meant for Java (or perhaps because I wasn't familiar with it). But it's a good open source option.

Answer (score 1):

I am also working with mod_wsgi, python, apache software stack.  I am using WingIDE as my environment, which gives you debugging capabilities.  If you are vi person it has a VI/VIM personality which coupled with auto-completion makes for a very productive work environment.

Comment: @Mohan interesting, I love vim and I can't wait to check this out.  Maybe I don't WANT to use PyDev :)

Comment: @Mohan, thanks for the suggestion but I am hoping to find something free/open source.  I modified the question to make this clear.  Thanks!

Comment: WingIDE does have an "free version"... FYI....

Comment: @AJ No Problem... The free version does exist.  However, I have a licence and I am not aware of what the differences are.

Answer (score 0):

What about IDLE?  It's bundled with Python distributions.

Comment: @Jeff sure I'd consider this...what are the features about it that you like over other IDEs?

Comment: IDLE doesn't really meet the question criteria.

Comment: It has syntax highlighting, an integrated debugger, and it's simple.  Actually, maybe it's a bit too simple.  Plus, true, it doesn't satisfy your requirement for source control.  I like it when I need to write some quick code.  I frankly prefer PyDev, and it does fit all your needs, but I got the impression from your other comment that you don't seem to want to use that.

Answer (score 0):

I've been using Komodo Edit for a while now and it's quite good for Python development.  It's free and I think it's also open-source now, though it wasn't always so.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it is powerful enough for you but you can try [Komodo Edit](https://www.activestate.com/products/komodo-edit/). AFAK it has no debugging or SCM but it is lightweight ;)

Answer (score 0):

*"syntax checking/highlighting, source control, debugging, and other IDE goodies"*

Emacs fits this criteria, if you use the right extensions. Though it does have a much steeper learning curve than any IDE I know of.